# How to root my Motorola Flipside?

Tags: rooting, linux, motorola-flipside

I am a relatively new Android user, but I have a bit of experience with Linux.

My new Motorola Flipside MB508 has quite a few unwanted preinstalled applications on it, which I would like to remove. However, I need to root the device to do this.

What is the easiest way to root a Motorola Flipside on Linux?

`*`edit`*` I tried using SuperOneClick, but I am running Fedora (17) and it doesn't work in Wine.

Answer (score 0):

AndroidEvolved has guides for [rooting your Motorola Flipside](http://androidevolved.com/forums/flipside-root-roms-kernels-development/1648-motorola-flipside-root-guides.html).

The easiest solution is to use [SuperOneClick](http://shortfuse.org/?page_id=2).

1. Download SuperOneClick, and extract it.
2. Connect your device to the computer. Ensure that SD card is not mounted. If it is mounted, unmount it.
3. Enable USB Debugging from Phone –> Settings –> Application Development –> Development.
4. Open SuperOneClick.exe.
5. Click on Universal tab if you are going to root any Android device like Nexus One, Galaxy S, Droid etc. Click on Samsung Captivate if that's your phone.
6. Click on Root tab and wait for the process to finish. [this will take some time]
7. Once completd, you would get a popup box that would confirm that rooting has been successful.
8. Restart your phone.

[Source](http://androidfornoob.com/android-noobs-guide-to-root-using-superoneclick/)

Comment: Thanks, but SuperOneClick doesn't seem work for me on Fedora (I forgot to mention I'm running Linux).

Answer (score 0):

Try [FramaRoot](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/framaroot/root-framaroot-one-click-apk-to-root-t2130276).
 
It doesn't need a PC to connect to and no ADB is required.

It simply installs Super SU on your device. You don't need to be worried about breaking... If it couldn't root your device it simply avoids installing super user.